# Is the diagonal locally compact in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is the space $\Delta = \{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{\omega}: x_{n} = x_{m}\text{ for all }n,m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$ locally compact in the the product space $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$?

I believe that it is true. Here is my reasoning:

Let $\pi_{i}$ denote the projection mapping associated with the index $i$. Consider $\mathbf{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ and let $U = \pi_{1}^{-1}((-1, 1))\cap\Delta$ be an open neighborhood. Then since all coordinates of a point in $U$ must be equal we have $U = (-1, 1)^{\omega}\cap\Delta$. Assuming the Tychonoff theorem $U$ is contained in the compact set $[-1, 1]^{\omega}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff we can show that $\Delta$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$. Since $[-1, 1]^{\omega}\cap\Delta$ is a closed subspace of a compact space it is compact (in particular, a compact subspace of $\Delta$).

Is the above reasoning correct or is the statement false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Delta$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, so..